# How to add solar DC output, Wind DC output and Fuel cell DC output to create a DC bus

Tags: power, dc, solar-cell

How to add solar DC output, Wind DC output and Fuel cell DC output to create a DC bus.
My doubt is, Is it possible to connect the outputs of different type of power sources(considering the DC voltage is same for all).

Comment: Connect how? In parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Why "considering the DC voltage is the same for all." The voltage won't be the same for all unless each one includes a DC to DC converter that will assure that. What you are asking is "how do I go about designing a DC microgrid?" The basic requirement would be to install DC to DC converters for each source. The converters must be suitable for DC microgrid connection. You also need to consider the connection of your storage batteries and your system for controlling the use of sources. Presumably, you wouldn't bring the fuel cell on line unless the other sources were fully utilized and the storage is nearing depletion.

I think that only a very general overview can be provided here.

Answer (score 0):

Connect each source in parallel,through a diode.(one diode per branch)

Each source has internal resistance, that causes a voltage drop when loaded. (adjust)

The only problem may be that the source with the highest voltage and lowest internal resistance will carry bigger portion of the load.

If one source has a lot lower voltage, that source may not contribute.

The benefit of the diodes is that when a source is not producing power, it will not consume power from other sources.